# DJango app on Nginx - Redirecting links to other servers back to my domain. How do i fix this?

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, gunicorn, certbot

So i messed up when i registered my certbot file and only registered it for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) instead of that plus domain.com to my website so i forced all proxy_pass to the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to be able to deploy except now when i try to link to my shopify store it redirects the link right back to my [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Here is my nginx.conf, hopefully someone knows what i did wrong...

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 4096;
        # multi_accept on;
}


http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        gzip on;

    server {
            listen 80;
            return 444;
    }
    server {
            server_name www.example.com, example.com;
            listen 80;
            return 307 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        server_name www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

            location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.;
                  proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;                            
                  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_redirect off;
            }
            location /static/ {
                    autoindex on;
                    alias /var/www/www.example.com/static/;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried changing the ports that were listening to what and tried messing with the headers, eliminating some to see if anything would work but so far nothing and this is so far the ideal settings for my gunicorn to run on

Answer (score -1):

Well, it was my DNS server....